# Why is implicit pointer of pointer to pointer conversion legal?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

I recently came across some code on stackoverflow where pointers to pointers where used to change allocated memory. While checking the code I made the mistake to add an ampersand to a pointer so make a pointer to a pointer still the compiler happily compiled and runtime errors occured. As an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int **p) {
  printf("Pointer is at %p\n", p);
}

int main(void) {
  int *p = 0;
  func(p);
  func(&p);
  int **pp = &p;
  func(&pp);
  return 0;
}
```

I do understand that C has significantly lower restrictions for pointers than C++ and allows something like `char *buf = malloc(SIZE)` while not allowed in C++. I see it as a convenience because it happens so much in C.

Nevertheless, I think that the amount of references is a great source of errors and I wonder why one might allow this especially since `int` is different from `int*`. Furthermore I want to know if the C standard says something about this.

**EDIT**
I compiled it under ideone.com which likely does not show warnings. My local clang compiler as well as gcc do give warnings. Still, why are they just warnings when they represent different things.

---

PS, I feel like something like this should have been asked in the last six years of SO. If this a duplicate I am sorry for not finding one.

Comment: I have to admit, I only tested it with ideone.com, but they just use gcc.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that, since they tagged as C++ as well.

Comment: Sry, thought C++ is involved because this is somewhat a comparison

Comment: Both gcc and clang complain loudly about the code posted (in C mode, even without `-Wall`).

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior!

Comment: @Mat: GCC 4.9.2 on ideone doesn't complain: http://ideone.com/Xlp3Gb

Comment: @pepe: weird, even GCC 4.5 complains: http://goo.gl/3GDKDw

Comment: @haccks No it doesn't.

Comment: Uhm, maybe ideone is turning warnings off. Still **why is that a warning and not an error**? Why does the Standard allow that?

Comment: @Havenard; Yes it is.

Comment: @haccks He never access the data that pointer is pointing to, so whatever address you assign to it is irrelevant. Theres no undefined behaviour on sight.

Comment: @peppe: Other than the `#error` directive, C merely requires diagnostic messages for any syntax error or constraint violation. A diagnostic message may be a non-fatal warning. The lesson: *don't ignore warnings*.

Comment: @Havenard; But he is using wrong format specifier.

Comment: @peppe Because pointers will be pointers, in some sense they are all compatible, so theres nothing actually preventing compilation from being successful. The compiler only got reason enough to issues a warning.

Comment: @peppe: See my answer again. You _can_ make it an error. (at least with gcc).

Comment: @Olaf: I know about `-Werror`, that has nothing to do with the fact that this is considered a "mere" warning rather than a fatal error. The question is  tagged as `language-lawyer` so what @KeithThompson said stands ("mere diagnostic required"). Another question would be why compiler authors think this should be non-fatal.

Comment: @peppe: Well, gcc _does_ complain by default (no additional warnings actively enabled). For the standard allowing this, I agree with you completely. I do suspect some legacy code vendors, who are afraid to fix their (then?) broken code (for the costs, I presume). Note that e.g. malloc()&friends once passed `char *`, not `void *` as they have to now.

Comment: @Havenard: There would still be explicit casts available.

Comment: @Olaf Naturally. All that does is suppress the warning though, because you are letting the compiler know your intentions weren't accidental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion is *not* legal. More precisely, there is no implicit conversion from `int*` to `int**`, or from `int***` to `int**`. Attempting to pass an `int*` or an `int***` to a function that requires an `int**` argument is a *constraint violation*; any conforming compiler must diagnose it. (The diagnostic message may be a non-fatal warning.)

When I compile your code with gcc, even with default options (which makes gcc non-conforming), I get several warnings:

```
c.c: In function ‘func’:
c.c:4:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("Pointer is at %x\n", p);
   ^
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:9:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   func(p);
   ^
c.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 void func(int **p) {
      ^
c.c:12:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   func(&pp);
   ^
c.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int ***’
 void func(int **p) {
      ^
```

I don't know why ideone doesn't complain about it (http://ideone.com/uzeXur).

Comment: by looking at the output from ideone, it seems that ideone is internally trying to change the code. Else looking at the output from gcc compiled executable, it says `Pointer is at (nil)` for the first case.

Comment: To complement this `6.5.16.1` of the C11 standard says clearly that in an assignment both sides have to be compatible. But according to 4. Conformance this, as you said, does not mean that translation has to stop.

Comment: @henje: No, it doesn't say that both sides have to have compatible types;  there numerous cases where the types can be incompatible and an implicit conversion is performed.

Comment: I meant pointer types: `the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler apparently has no warnings enabled:

```
int main()
{
    int *p = 0, **p2 = p;

...

$ gcc -std=c11 test.c -lncurses
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:21: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  int *p = 0, **p2 = p;
                     ^
```

So, gcc complains very well. That site might have disabled warnings or swallows it. It should do neither.

For gcc, You can also turn all warnings to errors with `-Werror` or just some specific: `-Werror=<name of warning>`. For this, it would be `strict-aliasing`.

Reason this is not default is propably historical reasons. Making it an error by default might break too much legacy or otherwise broken software in the wild.

The reason it does not produce an error might be found [here in the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3). Sentence 7. It is only UB if the pointer is not properly aligned for the receiving pointer or dereferenced (which is not done here).

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with null pointers. What do you mean by "see different"?

Answer (score 1):

I think ideone is just soft on the warnings. Without `-Wall` or any extra warning flags on my computer gcc gives me

```
test_ptrs.c: In function ‘func’:
test_ptrs.c:4:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("Pointer is at %x\n", p);
   ^
test_ptrs.c: In function ‘main’:
test_ptrs.c:9:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   func(p);
   ^
test_ptrs.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 void func(int **p) {
      ^
test_ptrs.c:12:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   func(&pp);
   ^
test_ptrs.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int ***’
 void func(int **p) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Using wrong specifier to print a data type invoke undefined behavior. Change `%x` to `%p` and cast argument of `printf` to `void *` and you will have warnings.

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/19KBSA)</kbd>